# Error Occured in Installing Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

> when i install tomcat7 by executing cmd : ~$ sudo apt-get install tomcat7,
>   I got this:

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 libubuntuoneui-3.0-1

Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.

Suggested packages:

tomcat7-docs tomcat7-admin tomcat7-examples tomcat7-user libtcnative-1
The following NEW packages will be installed:

tomcat7

0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Need to get 0 B/37.3 kB of archives.

After this operation, 357 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...

Selecting previously unselected package tomcat7.

(Reading database ... 318381 files and directories currently installed.)

Unpacking tomcat7 (from .../tomcat7_7.0.26-1ubuntu1.2_all.deb) ...

Processing triggers for ureadahead ...

Setting up tomcat7 (7.0.26-1ubuntu1.2) ...

Creating config file /etc/default/tomcat7 with new version
Adding system user `tomcat7' (UID 118) ...

Adding new user `tomcat7' (UID 118) with group`tomcat7' ...

Not creating home directory `/usr/share/tomcat7'.

- tomcat7 is not installed

invoke-rc.d: initscript tomcat7, action "start" failed

> So please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got something wrong with your packages. About Tomcat install, I would rather advise these steps:

1. Download Tomcat from the official [downloads site](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi). Choose whatever version fits fort your OS.
2. Unextract files and place them into any custom location.
3. Make sure you've got ***`JRE_HOME`*** set. You can add to ***`.bashrc`*** file the following line:

   `export JRE_HOME=/.../pathToJVMInstalled`
   mine is
   `export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre`
4. You may also want to add Tomcat binaries to the path. You can complete this adding the following lines to ***`.bashrc`*** file:
   `export TOMCAT_BIN=/.../pathToJVMInstalled/bin`
   `PATH=$PATH:$TOMCAT_BIN`
5. Done.

Answer (score 0):

In order to succeed with `tomcat7` package installation I had to install also `openjdk-7-jdk` (`openjdk-7-jre` would be probably sufficient).
Before I had already `oracle-java8-installer` but apparently that was not recognised by the `tomcat7` package even when I tried to explicitly set `JAVA_HOME`.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk tomcat7
```